# BGS/LQM Groundhog - drawing a water table

Tags: gis

I am using the new BGS Groundhog Desktop software.

I have tried to draw a water table line but it is just shows as a black line with a water table label.  Is there an automatic way to get a blue line with the upside down triangle symbol

Comment: Consider asking this over at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the shape layer that contains the line is active by single-clicking on it in the layers control to the right of the cross-section graphics panel. The active layer is highlighted in orange.

Single-click on the line in question to make it active. When active, the nodes of the line will display in green.

Right-click on the line and you should see an option to "Tag Shape As...". Click that option and a selection dialog will appear. From the pull-down list, select "Water Level" and click OK.

Click away from the line to deselect it, and the line should now appear as a blue line with the inverted triangular blue water level symbols at each end.